# QuickFix C++ how to validate fields to have values for outgoing FIX message

Tags: c++, validation, quickfix

We use QuickFixC++.

I noticed outgoing FIX message ( IOI ) from our system has empty price value (tag 44) as 44=-nan.

Our system's QuickFix has **ValidateFieldsHaveValues** as Y ( default value). Is it only for incoming message ? If so, is there any configuration option for validating outgoing message ?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: The value is not truly empty. NaN is a valid value for a [QuickFIX `Price`](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/master/src/C%2B%2B/FieldTypes.h#L628) field (defined as a `double`), so the message passes this layer of validation. You may need to inspect your outgoing IOI messages in `ToApp` instead. Or, look into why the price is being set as NaN in the first place.

Comment: My gut feeling is you use them both ways while creating or receiving. Best would be debug and confirm.

Comment: See this question for some help to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030492/how-do-you-validate-values-for-an-order-using-quickfix/42673088#42673088