# How do you validate values for an order using QuickFix

Tags: python, validation, quickfix, fix-protocol, vim-quickfix

I'm a beginner with quickfix and I'm not sure if the problem I'm having is trivial or not. I want to validate the values of an order using quickfix such as `symbol`, `price`, `quantity`, etc. Does quickfix provide a function in python that validates if a price is of type `PRICE` and that its value is valid (for example: 4.23)?

Here is the reference: http://www.quickfixengine.org/FIX42.html#field_Price

Comment: No Quickfix doesn't do that and it shouldn't. It only checks for message validity. You need to do this yourself in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DumbCoder says in the comment QuickFix does not validate the contents of a message. If the PRICE (FIX4.2 tag 44) field is defined to be a float type for example, it can be *any* float value be it negative, zero or positive. PRICE types in financial markets are not *usually* negative although there are exceptions.

So it is up to you to validate the message contents for the type of message you are processing. A fill message (e.g. you bought 100 shares of AAPL for 123.45) for a simple stock order would generally never have a negative price value but it is left up to you the programmer to add this contextual validation.

As an example of an exception consider a fill message in a futures markets for a spread order. This in an instruction to trade two separate instruments together somewhat atomically and could result in a negative price so that you got money back *and* a position in a contract.